# Why isn’t the button triggering the second function?

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to get two functions to trigger with one button. Could someone help me what I did wrong?

I know that I can just add the text from function one from function two, but my goal was to complete two functions under one button.

```
<p id="demo" style="display:none">JavaScript can show hidden HTML elements.</p>

<p id="demoTwo" style="display:none">Hello JavaScript!</p>

<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('demo').style.display='block'" onclick="document.getElementById('demoTwo').style.display='block'">Click Me!</button>
```

I was wanting both function’s text to appear at the button click. However, only the first function completed.

Comment: Element attributes must be uniqe, you cannot have two `onclick` handlers. You can do this in one `onclick` handler `onclick="document.getElementById('demo').style.display='block';document.getElementById('demoTwo').style.display='block'"`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a function to be able to do that:

```
onclick="showDemos()"
```

Then in your JavaScript:

```
function showDemos() {
  document.getElementById("demo").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("demoTwo").style.display = "block";
}
```

```js
function showDemos() {
  document.getElementById("demo").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("demoTwo").style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<p id="demo" style="display:none">JavaScript can show hidden HTML elements.</p>

<p id="demoTwo" style="display:none">Hello JavaScript!</p>

<button type="button" onclick="showDemos()">Click Me!</button>
```

Inline listeners are generally discouraged - you should use `addEventListener`:

```js
function showDemos() {
  document.getElementById("demo").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("demoTwo").style.display = "block";
}

document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", showDemos);
```

```html
<p id="demo" style="display:none">JavaScript can show hidden HTML elements.</p>

<p id="demoTwo" style="display:none">Hello JavaScript!</p>

<button type="button" id="button">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: You don't *need* a function to do this, but it's certainly a good suggestion.

Comment: The teacher wasn’t allowing us to us external files yet. Thanks for the info!